# Mailing out text file in table format using shell script

Tags: shell

I am also looking for the same,
My text file have df -h information of my server,need to send the detail to my mail in table format.

```
Use% Avail Used Filesystem
47% 28G 24G rootfs
0% 11M 0 udev
1% 396M 160k tmpfs
47% 28G 24G /dev/disk/
0% 5.3M 0 tmpfs
1% 793M 13k tmpfs
2% 50G 520M /dev/xvdg
24% 39G 12G /dev/xvdf
```

I need table format 
as
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64nBa.png)

I have tried your steps but getting mail as below

```
input="/home/infrarunsvc/output.txt"
tmpfile="/home/infrarunsvc/tmpfile.html"

echo 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii" ' > "$tmpfile"
awk 'BEGIN{print "<html><body><table border=1>"} {print "<tr>";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print "<td>" $i"</td>";print "</tr>"} END{print "</table></body></html>"}' "$input" >> "$tmpfile"
mail -s "test" xxxxxx.com < "$tmpfile"
```

Kindly help me in formatting it.

Comment: You seem to be missing some context.

Comment: I am getting below result in mail.
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii" 
<html><body><table border=1>
<tr>
<td>Use%</td>
<td>Avail</td>
<td>Used</td>
<td>Filesystem</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>47%</td>
<td>28G</td>
<td>24G</td>
<td>rootfs</td>

I need it in tabular format.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this;

```
#!/bin/bash
df -h > /home/infrarunsvc/output.txt
tmpfile="/home/infrarunsvc/tmpfile.html"
input="/home/infrarunsvc/output.txt"
echo '<html><body><table border=1>' > "$tmpfile"
awk '{print "<tr>";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print "<td>" $i"</td>";print "</tr>"} END{print "</table></body></html>"}' "$input" >> "$tmpfile"
 cat $tmpfile | mail -s "$(echo -e "Test\nContent-Type: text/html")"     
yourmailaddress@...com
```

Comment: I am still getting result as below to the mail.. why me not getting in Table format.

<html><body><table border=1>
<tr>
<td>Use%</td>
<td>Avail</td>
<td>Used</td>
<td>Filesystem</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>47%</td>
<td>28G</td>
<td>24G</td>
<td>rootfs</td>
</tr>

Can some one provide a simple script to do df -h and get the detail to my mail id in table format.

Comment: I am not sure.. why its not working for me..
I am trying this in my aws bastion server.